# Can I disable asyncronous validation with redux form on form submit?

Tags: redux-form

This question is specific to redux-form.

I am using asyncronous validation for a field but don't want to re-validate on form submit as the validation is expensive.

I've looked at this github issue https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/681 and the suggestion was to memoize the async validation function. I don't want to go back to the server for this, so is there a way to access the store inside asyncValidate?

From the redux-form code, it looks like it should be possible to check the fields for async errors inside the `handleSubmit` function, rather than calling [`asyncValidate()`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/handleSubmit.js#L37). Could this be added as a configuration option to redux-form?

Answer (score 2):

[`v6.0.0-alpha.8`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v6.0.0-alpha.8), released yesterday, introduced a [`shouldAsyncValidate()`](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.8/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-shouldasyncvalidate-params-boolean-optional-) config parameter that addresses this specific issue.

Comment: do you know more or less when v6 will support `plugin()` on its reducer?

Comment: No specific date, but it's coming asap.